# How to move a tab between tabs using the keyboard in google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, keyboard-shortcuts

It is possible to move a tab in google chrome just with a keyboard-shortcut?
For example: Ctrl + Shift + Right > move the current tab to the right.

I know that you can simple use the mouse but It could be really helpful to do it in this way.

PLEASE DON'T CONFUSE THIS QUESTION WITH OPENING NEW TABS, IT'S JUST MOVING ALREADY OPENED TABS, LIKE SORTING TABS WITH THE KEYBOARD. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd> works in Chromium, perhaps also in Chrome..

Disclaimer: apparently these shortcuts don't work on all platforms. The question did not mention any particular platform.

Comment: Negative, just tested.

Comment: It works in Google Chrome ubuntu system. Thanks @Jonas

Comment: @Shiazure It is a little weird why the `Ctrl-Shift-PgUp/PgDn` key doesn't work on Windows. This plugin will bring these keyborad shortcut back. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-reo/moigagbiaanpboaflikhdhgdfiifdodd

Comment: works on chrom on macOs as well. I use `control + shift + fn + up/down`

Answer (score 1):

My Chrome on Windows does not respond to `Ctrl+Shift+PgUp` so I used an [extension named Rearrange Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rearrange-tabs/ccnnhhnmpoffieppjjkhdakcoejcpbga/).

Under this extension, moving selected tab(s) left on Mac is `Ctrl+Shift+Left`. For Windows it is `Shift+Alt+Left`.

Comment: The extension seems very useful. Is there a reason, why you are linking the related tab instead of the description? Might be useful to name the extesion (Rearrange Tabs) and the shortcuts. To move selected tab(s) left on Mac: Ctrl+Shift+Left, on Windows: Shift+Alt+Left

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> to the right, and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Tab</kbd> to the left on Windows and on Mac (circa late 2017).

Comment: This doesn't move the tab, it just changes which one is selected.

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood the question 4 years ago, whoops.